# Excel record price ticker data every 5 min

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with the price of various currencies fed in through API and updating every 5 minutes. I'm trying to figure out a way for Excel to record the history of a particular currency every 5 minutes and to list all the historic prices down a particular column. I found this code here ([link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5216-excel-record-changing-values.html)) but it doesn't seem to be working properly (see code below).

```
Dim xVal As String
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/8/22
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static xCount As Integer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("I2").Address Then
        Range("AC2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = xVal
        xCount = xCount + 1
    Else
        If xVal <> Range("C2").Value Then
         Range("AC2").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = xVal
        xCount = xCount + 1
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    xVal = Range("I2").Value
End Sub
```

When I use the above code, it'll progressively create a list of prices, but the problem is that the recorded figures are all the same (see below screenshot). The underlying price has clearly been changing. How can I fix this or does anyone have a better code I can use? Many thanks!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f3A6.png)

Comment: Try to use _Range("I2").Value_ instead of _xVal_ in our _Sub Worksheet_Change_

Comment: I'd look at using `Application.OnTime` if you only need the value copied every 5 mins.

Comment: @Shrotter, do I just replace all of the text "xval" in the code to "Range("I2").Value" instead? Forgive me, I'm a novice at vba.

Comment: @TimWilliams How do I use the Application.OnTime? Can I see the code? Many thanks.

Comment: There are plenty of examples here on SO (https://www.google.com/search?q=application.ontime+site%3Astackoverflow.com) or to be found via Google, or you could start with the MS docs for the method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime